# Input File Type Skip Some Files

Tags: php, html, forms, http-post

I am selecting 28 files and the form posts only 20 files.

So, how can I increase the number of files selected in html form?

Following is the html code for file input.

```
<input type="file" class="form-control template-images" name="files[]" multiple>
```

Comment: What is set for `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`  configuration values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the value [max-file-uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) settings in your php.ini file:

```
;Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```